# Excel: Accept only unique values in coloumn

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010

In Microsoft Excel, I want to filter entries so that only **unique domain names** appear. Suppose I have 10 records:

```
 1. www.manish.com
 2. joo.mj.com 
 3. ko.kiop.eu  
 4. mail.manish.com  
 5. kio.manish.eu 
 6. ftp.mj.com  
 7. ftp.kiop.com
 8. www.makil.com 
 9. www.craftio.com 
10. extension.telep.com
```

My desired result (unique domain names) would be:

```
 1. www.manish.com
 2. joo.mj.com
 3. ko.kiop.com
 4. www.makil.com 
 5. www.craftio.com 
 6. extension.telep.com
```

Comment: @PeterL.: Though being new to excel, I have tried as much as I can like searching for a value and deleting corresponding row. Help me on how to extract domain name from a string like just `mj` from joo.mj.com

Comment: It's unclear from question why you select as unique e.g. `joo.mj.com` - and not `ftp.mj.com`? what is the criteria?

Comment: It is like the domain name should be unique. I would select anyone from `joo.mj.com` and `ftp.mj.com` whichever comes first (like First Come First Serve) and delete the rest. Clear @PeterL.?

Comment: I suppose your actual data does not have these leading numbers like `1.` ?

Comment: And what about domains like `xxxxx.co.uk` or `yyyyyyy.com.de` - do you have these?

Comment: No, they don't have these numbers. Have specified these just for numbering, thats it!

And if its `www.google.co.uk` and `www.google.in`, it should keep only first one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7574/discussion-between-developer-by-blood-and-peter-l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input conditions and data is placed in column `A` starting `A1`, do the following:

1. Type in `B1`: `=MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)-FIND(".",A1)-1)` and autofill down the list - this will return domain name, or more precisely - part of string between 1st and 2nd `.`
2. Type in `C1`: `=VLOOKUP("*"&B1&"*",A:A,1,0)` and autofill down the list - this will return the first match for the domain name from the array in column `A`.
3. Copy and **paste special as values** entire column `C` to e.g. column `D`.
4. Use Ribbon `Data > Remove Duplicates` to remain only unique records.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/35wtuqsex7u57as/UnikueDomainNames.xlsx

Comment: Unable to find sample file !

Comment: Try again, this works fine unless dropbox access is blocked in your network. In any case formulas are working, do the job on your own.

Comment: Wohooo! The code works great :) Thanks Peter, you're genius in Excel :)

P.S.: Will close this after I am done with the project. In case of any assistance, will revert back to you :)

Comment: @DeveloperbyBlood Glad to help! As soon as this Q is solved - submit a new one for future cases, but tend to show your efforts first - such way people tend to more willingly to help) Good luck!

Comment: Hey Peter, there is one modification from the superiors. They told I want both i.e. `www.google.co.in` and `www.google.co.uk` and in links like `www.google.co.in` and `mail.google.co.in` the first come dirst serve should follow.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Also, has one more coloumn attached to it. Say coloumn B, want those values according to that of coloumn A, i.e. entire record. Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide a new sample of original and desired data uoutput with ALL your wishes collected at once.

Comment: Lets say, what I have given is Coloumn A. There is a coloumn corresponding to it, which have some values say 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, etc. Now whenever I choose an entry in col A after sorting it (as we have done earlier), that corresponding values of coloumn B should be there in the final table. Got me, Peter?

Comment: I don't mind making wishes when you're my genie in excel! :D