# Extract strings from second last dot to end

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have values in a coloumn as:

```
  mail.google.com, 
  m.kilo.keepay.excel.com,
  zero.one.seven.eight.xyz.com
```

I want the output like

```
google.com, excel.com and xyz.com
```

Please help me with the query.

Comment: I am able to fetch .com but failing to get whole domain name i.e. like xyz.com

Query used: =RIGHT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)

Comment: Any idea @CharlieRB ?

Comment: @CharlieRB this is from http://superuser.com/questions/554130/excel-accept-only-unique-values-in-coloumn/

Comment: @PeterL. It might be the same person asking, but it's not a duplicate question. The previous was asking how to filter unique values. This one is asking how to trim the data in the field.

Comment: @CharlieRB this is just to answer "What have you tried?" ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your input starts from `A1` and down, use this formula in `B1` and autofill:

`=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE($A1,".","#",LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1,".",""))-1))),A1)`

This will handle `google.com` strings as well - these which are top-level domains as it is)

Comment: Works as smooth and error free like a butter. Thanks again, Peter! :)

Comment: Happy to help!)

Comment: Assuming it is URLs in the format above this is an awesome solution. Just watch out for tripart TLDs (e.g. bbc.co.uk or sbs.com.au).

Comment: @Gary assuming the input this is ok, but tripods where warned about before: http://superuser.com/questions/554130/excel-accept-only-unique-values-in-coloumn/ thanks for the catch anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom function in you excel file (described how to do it here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/creating-custom-functions-HA001111701.aspx)

function like this:

```
Function TrimURL(url As String)
   s = StrReverse(url)
   d1 = InStr(s, ".")
   If d1 = 0 Then
    TrimURL = url
    Exit Function
   End If
   d2 = InStr(d1 + 1, s, ".", vbTextCompare)
   If d2 = 0 Then
    TrimURL = url
    Exit Function
   End If
   r = Left(s, d2 - 1)
   TrimURL = StrReverse(r)
End Function
```

and then use it in cell like that:

```
=TrimURL(A1)
```